# Sunlight degradation of butyric and propionic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

As I understand from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_odor) article sweat is metabolized by skin flora primarily to butyric and propionic acid. What will sunlight do to these acids? Will my cloth smell less if dried in sunlight?
My concerns is that if drying in sun will remove odour fomr clothes as sunlight will cause degradation of odor causing chemicals(what ever they may be) and bacteria.
Sunlight should break bind in organic chemicals and make them odourless

Comment: Hello and welcome to Chemistry.SE. You might want to do a couple things to help clarify your question. First, you could [edit] in a link to the Wikipedia article. Also, it might be helpful if you expanded in a couple sentences why you think your clothes would smell less if "dried in tropical dry heat", and also just what that phrase means (i.e. dry heat with sunlight or without sunlight). Just some suggestions. Best of luck!

Comment: FYI: There are actually quite a few rather complex molecules responsible for body odor. According to Wikipedia: "The main components of human axillary odor are unsaturated or hydroxylated branched fatty acids with E-3M2H (E-3-methyl-2-hexenoic acid) and HMHA (3-hydroxy-3-methyl-hexanoic acid), sulfanylalkanols and particularly 3M3SH (3-methyl-3-sulfanylhexan-1-ol), and the odoriferous steroids androstenone (5α-androst-16-en-3-one) and androstenol (5α-androst-16-en-3α-ol)." And as you said, butyric and propionic acids also definitely play a role in body odor.

Comment: @airhuff edited question